# Program not catching IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, exception, outofrangeexception

I'm following an old YouTube guide for C# learning and I'm stuck on one of the challenges for error handling.

```
class Program
{
    static Board myBoard = new Board(8);

    public static Cell setCurrentCell()
    {
        int currentRow, currentColumn;
        // get x and y coordinates from the user. return a cell location
        Console.Write("Enter a current row number: ");

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                currentRow = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                break;
            }

            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.Write("Input has to be a number, try again:");
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input was out of range, try a number between 0 and 8.");
                Console.Write("Please try again: ");
            }
        }


        Console.Write("Enter the current column number: ");
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                currentColumn = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                break;
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.Write("Input has to be a number, try again:");
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input was out of range, try a number between 0 and 8.");
                Console.Write("Please try again: ");
            }
        }
      }
        return myBoard.theGrid[currentRow, currentColumn];
    }
}
```

I'm trying to catch an error if user enters a number out of bounds but the catch just skips over it and then throws the error anyways. what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: A perfect time to learn how to use the debugger. The exception is thrown outside your catch blocks and it will even tell you that. Have a look at the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Following [`Int32.Parse` method documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse) – exception type `IndexOutOfRangeException` is not handled here.

If you want to check that value is less than `Int32` min value or greater than `Int32` max value, you should catch [`OverflowException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.overflowexception).

Answer (score 0):

`IndexOutOfRangeException` is throw by an attempt to access an indexable collection (arrays, `List<T>`, anything that implements `IList<T>`, etc.) using an invalid index - less than 0 or greater than or equal to the collection size.

Here's the first `try` block in your code:

```
try
{
    currentRow = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    break;
}
```

Nothing in that block is attempting to index a collection, so we wouldn't expect `IndexOutOfRangeException` to be thrown. In fact there are only two things in there that can throw an exception at all (`int.Parse` and `Console.ReadLine`), neither of which can throw `IndexOutOfRangeException` under any circumstances.

There's only one line in your code that performs an indexing operation on a collection and that's the final `return` statement... which is not contained in a `try...catch` statement.

---

What you're trying to achieve is to range-check the entered values. There are a couple of ways to do this, but if you insist on using exceptions (which I wouldn't do, but you're learning I guess) then you can check the inputs by attempting to index the board's `theGrid` array after the parse in each `try` block like this:

```
try
{
    currentRow = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    var test = myBoard.theGrid[currentRow, 0];
    break;
}
```

And for `currentColumn`:

```
try
{
    currentColumn = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    var test = myBoard.theGrid[0, currentColumn];
    break;
}
```

If the entered value (`currentRow` or `currentColumn`) is out of bounds then this will throw the `IndexOutOfRangeException` as expected. (The `0` in the other index is guaranteed to not throw unless the row/column count is 0.)